# Ionic select: pre selecte value is invisible until clicked once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic6

I just created an ion-select in ionic version 6.
My problem is that i have successfully pre selected a value when the page loads, but this pre select value does not get shown in the UI?!

It just appears after I have clicked the select, but before it does not appear (as you can see on pic 2). I load the data in the ionViewWillEnter Method and pre select it with an NgModel!

You can see it here:

[Looks like this when the page was loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KULg1.png)

[Looks like this when I open the select (pre select value was succesful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hopfv.png)

HTML Code for the select

```
    <ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item lines="inset">
      <ion-label hidden>Abteilungen wählen</ion-label>
      <ion-select (ionChange)="loadOpenTicketsForDepts()" style="min-width: 100%"
        placeholder="Abteilungen wählen..." multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartments" cancelText="Abbruch"
        okText="OK">
        <ion-select-option value="{{dept.id}}" *ngFor="let dept of departments">
          {{dept.name}}
        </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Typescript data loading:

```
  ionViewWillEnter(): void {
//1. get department where logged in emp is working in
this.authService.getPersNr().then((res) => {
  //now load dept
  this.ticketService.getEmployeeByName(res).subscribe(emp => {

    const costcenter = emp.costcentreId;

    this.costCentreService.getDepartmentById(costcenter).subscribe(dept => {
      //add to selected departments if it is not already in
      if (this.selectedDepartments.includes(String(dept.id)) == false) {
        this.selectedDepartments.push(String(dept.id))
      }
      //now load tickets for all selected departments
      this.loadOpenTicketsForDepts();
    })
  })
})

this.costCentreService.getDepartments().subscribe(res => {
  this.departments = res;
})
```

}

Comment: Could you send me an example of your `this.selectedDepartments` value? Is it a string you are trying to bind to the ngModel?

Comment: Yeah it is an array of string values like: Array [ "3" ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to your selector named #departmentSelector:

```
 <ion-select #departmentSelector (ionChange)="loadOpenTicketsForDepts()" style="min-width: 100%"
    placeholder="Abteilungen wählen..." multiple [(ngModel)]="selectedDepartments" cancelText="Abbruch"
    okText="OK">
    <ion-select-option value="{{dept.id}}" *ngFor="let dept of departments">
      {{dept.name}}
    </ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Then You could access it from your typscript class after view Loaded:

Declare your reference:

```
  @ViewChild("departmentSelector") departmentSelector!: IonSelect;
```

Then You Could access it when view fully loaded:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){


//your async function ...

this.authService.getPersNr().then((res) => {
  //now load dept
  this.ticketService.getEmployeeByName(res).subscribe(emp => {

    const costcenter = emp.costcentreId;

    this.costCentreService.getDepartmentById(costcenter).subscribe(dept => {
      //add to selected departments if it is not already in
      if (this.selectedDepartments.includes(String(dept.id)) == false) {
       // this.selectedDepartments.push(String(dept.id))

this.departmentSelector.value = String(dept.id);
   
   }
      //now load tickets for all selected departments
      this.loadOpenTicketsForDepts();
    })
  })
})


//


}
```

Comment: WOW THANK YOU! Great solution it worked. But the View Child has to look like:  @ViewChild("departmentSelector") departmentSelector:IonSelect with the " "! ;) And the line this.departmentSelector.value = ids; has to look like this.departmentSelector.value=String(dept.id); - but thank you!